# Matching two vectors with mapply to create sequences

Tags: r, scope, sequence, mapply

Two vectors are given, `a` and `b`. The vectors contain startpoints (a) and endpoints (b) of various sequences. These sequences should be set to 1000 in a target vector `vec`. I am trying to use `mapply` for this purpose, but the outcome is not as expected.

```
a <- c(2,10,15)
b <- c(4,13,18)
vec <- sample(1:18,18)

mapply(function(a, b){
  vec[a:b] <- 1000; vec
},a,b)
```

I know I could do `vec[unlist(Map(":", a, b))] <- 1000` from another thread, but I would like to learn more about `mapply` and why it doesnt work as intended in this case.

The outcome comes in form of a matrix instead of a vector, i.e. the changes are not saved to the original vector. How could this be done? Probably an easy fix (but I cannot figure out anything in the documentation or anywhere else)

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   13   13
[2,] 1000    2    2
[3,] 1000   17   17
[4,] 1000   12   12
[5,]   14   14   14
[6,]    9    9    9
[7,]   16   16   16
[8,]    4    4    4
[9,]   15   15   15
[10,]   18 1000   18
[11,]    6 1000    6
[12,]    3 1000    3
[13,]   11 1000   11
[14,]    1    1    1
[15,]   10   10 1000
[16,]    7    7 1000
[17,]    5    5 1000
[18,]    8    8 1000
```

Comment: you could do `mapply(function(a, b){vec[a:b] <<- 1000},a,b)`. But, the unlist way is better - you normally don't want to use global assignment `<<-` if you can help it.

Comment: @jeremycg yeah that principally works, but it prints 3 x `1000` to the console during the process. As an alternative I tried to pass vec as an argument to `mapply`, but because of the different length the function didn't work properly anymore and created a lot of NAs.

Comment: mapply isn't really well suited to this task - you get 3 results out as `a` and `b` are 3 long. If you really want an apply in there, try `vec[unlist(sapply(1:length(a), function(x) seq(from = a[x], to = b[x])))]<-1000` but this is just the `Map` answer above converted to `sapply`

Comment: @jeremycg Alright thank you very much, this is what I needed to know for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to jeremycg.

There are 3 ways to do it:

1) Unlist, as mentioned already. Probably best way how to do it

```
vec[unlist(Map(":", a, b))] <- 1000
```

2) Use global assignment

```
mapply(function(a, b){vec[a:b] <<- 1000},a,b)
```

3) Using apply

```
vec[unlist(sapply(1:length(a), function(x) seq(from = a[x], to = b[x])))]<-1000
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapply` runs through `a` and `b` simultaneously and generates a sequence of results. The length of this sequence is equal to the length of `a` and `b`. In this case it's a sequence of three vectors, i.e. a matrix with 3 columns.

Comment: Alright I understand that. Is it possible to achieve the desired output (1 vector) by using apply at all (without defining global variables as suggested above)?